# Validating cross-shard transaction using Beacon chain snapshots?

Tags: sharding, cross-chain, beacon-chain, cross-shard-transaction

According to this article: ([Link to article](https://medium.com/nearprotocol/the-authoritative-guide-to-blockchain-sharding-part-1-1b53ed31e060)), there are two types of validation for **cross-shard transactions**: **Synchronous** and **Asynchronous**.

But the question is that why cannot we use **Beacon chain snapshots** (as a single common chain between all the shards) to validate such transactions "locally" and without need of communication with other shards for **each** cross-shard transaction, where Beacon chains include all the snapshots of all the shards.

**For example,** assuming a transaction is performed between shard#1 and shard#2, such that the credit part is in the shard#1 and the debit part is in the shard#2. Then, if both shards have a Beacon chain (including the snapshot of both shards), this transaction can be validated in **each shard locally** using the Beacon chain snapshots and without communicating with other shard.

Is there something that I do not consider?